# pass parameter from Ext JS button handler

Tags: button, extjs, handler

How to get username and password value from my button handler? When I code like this, I got error Uncaught ReferenceError: username is not defined

```
var auth = new Ext.FormPanel({
  labelWidth   : 75,
  frame        : true,
  width        : 320,
  autoHeight   : true,        
  defaultType  : 'textfield',
  monitorValid : true,
  defaults     : {
     anchor : '-10'
  },
  items:[{
     fieldLabel : 'Username',
     id         : 'username',
     allowBlank : false
  },{
     fieldLabel : 'Password',
     id         : 'password',
     inputType  : 'password',
     allowBlank : false
  }],   
     buttons:[{
     text : 'OK',
     handler: penggabunganRm(username, password)
  }]
});

var createWindow = new Ext.Window({
  title      : 'Input username and password',
  width      : 330,
  autoHeight : true,
  modal      : true,
  border     : false,
  layout     : 'fit',
  items      : auth
});

createWindow.show();

function penggabunganRm(username, password){
    if(username=='test' && password=='test'){
    }
}
```

I want to get value of username and password to `penggabunganRm()` function.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this code below:-

```
var auth = new Ext.FormPanel({
    labelWidth: 75,
    frame: true,
    width: 320,
    autoHeight: true,
    defaultType: 'textfield',
    monitorValid: true,
    defaults: {
        anchor: '-10'
    },
    items: [{
        fieldLabel: 'Username',
        id: 'username',
        name: 'username',
        allowBlank: false
    }, {
        fieldLabel: 'Password',
        id: 'password',
        name: 'password',
        inputType: 'password',
        allowBlank: false
    }],
    buttons: [{
        text: 'OK',
        handler: function () {
            penggabunganRm(this);
        }
    }]
});

var createWindow = new Ext.Window({
    title: 'Input username and password',
    width: 330,
    autoHeight: true,
    modal: true,
    border: false,
    layout: 'fit',
    items: auth
});

createWindow.show();

function penggabunganRm(button) {
    console.log(button.up('form').getValues());
    if (username == 'test' && password == 'test') {};
}
```

**[Working Example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2jbh)**

I have used **`name`** config both username and password fields.
Hope this will help/guide you.

Comment: I already use this code, but I got an error "button.up is not a function"